# Sequence convergence proof $\frac{n}{n+1}$ =1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, self-learning

Interested to know if my method for carrying out a standard converge proof is ok.

Prove: $\lim \frac{n}{n+1}=1$

proof: (Will not be showing scratch work)

Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$. Now for $n \geq N$, implies that $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$ $\implies$ $\epsilon > \frac{1}{n+1}$ $\implies$ $| \frac{n}{n+1}-1|< \epsilon$. Therefore from the definition of convergence $\lim\frac{n}{n+1}=1 $.

[]

Comment: Formulation is a bit unusual for me, but reasonning is correct. I would suggest: Let $\epsilon >0 $ ad $N$ s.t. $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$.
Then, for $n\geq N$ it holds
$$|\frac{n}{n+1}-1|=\frac{1}{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{N+1}<\epsilon.$$
As $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1$.

Comment: That works.  Personally I might say for any $\epsilon >0$ you can take any $N > \frac1\epsilon$ for simplicity, so for $n>N$ you have $\left|\frac{n}{n+1}-1\right|=\frac{1}{n+1}\lt \frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$

Comment: You should definitely not say what Surb said "Let $\epsilon>0$ and $N$ s.t". That would make the proof incomplete, since you still need to show that a pair $\epsilon, N$ with the conditions imposed, include arbitrary values of $\epsilon>0$. This is simple to prove, but there is no need to leave this logical gap that didn't exist in your argumentation.